# Problem with query on nested attribute DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

In my code I'm using the **`AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`** for interact with the DB.

My item structure is:

```json
{
 "docName": "drinkDoc",
 "sortKey": "RISTRETTO",
 "i18n": {
  "de": "",
  "en": "ristretto",
  "fr": "",
  "it": "ristretto"
 },
 "params": {
  "size": [
   "S",
   "M",
   "L",
   "XL"
  ]
 }
}
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the item filtering by i18n subproperties.

In my code I build a params object like this:

```json
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#docName = :docName",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#docName": "docName",
        "#i18n": "i18n.it"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":docName": "drinkDoc",
        ":drinkName": "ristretto"
    },
    "FilterExpression": "#i18n = :drinkName"
}
```

Then I execute the query in this way:

```js
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Unable to retrieve data. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                    return reject(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                }

                console.log("Read data succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                resolve(data.Items);

            });
```

So far so good.

The problem is that the query returns no item, but item exists in my database, as you can see:

[image]

What is wrong in this snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved from my self.

As indicated in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html

the code

```json
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#docName = :docName",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#docName": "docName",
        "#i18n": "i18n.it"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":docName": "drinkDoc",
        ":drinkName": "ristretto"
    },
    "FilterExpression": "#i18n = :drinkName"
}
```

must be replaced with

```json
{
    "TableName": "SmartCoffeeSkillTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#docName = :docName",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#docName": "docName",
        "#i18n": "i18n",
        "#locale": "it"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":docName": "drinks",
        ":drinkName": "caffè"
    },
    "FilterExpression": "#i18n.#locale = :drinkName"
}
```

that is to replace

`"FilterExpression": "#i18n = :drinkName"` with `"FilterExpression":` **`"#i18n.#locale`**  `= :drinkName"`